# Why does the local event variable in serverless behave differently?

Tags: javascript, node.js, serverless

Hello I'm using the serverless framework for testing lambda functions. I have the following code

```js
module.exports.send = async (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log("event", event);
}
```

When I invoke this function on local with the following mocked data using `serverless invoke local -f send -p mocked_data.txt`

where `mocked_data.txt` has

```json
{"name":"asfa","email":"test@test.com","content":"asadgdsgsdgsdagsdagsd"}
```

The variable event is populated with the exact data above already parsed

However, if I execute a POST to that endpoint from postman I get in the event variable

```json
event {
  resource: '/email/send',
  path: '/email/send',
  httpMethod: 'POST',
  headers: {
  // removed for brevity
  ,
    domainName: 'xxxxx.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
    apiId: 'xxxxx'
  },
  body: '{\n' +
    '    "name": "asfa",\n' +
    '    "email": "test@test.com",\n' +
    '    "content": "asadgdsgsdgsdagsdagsd"\n' +
    '}',
  isBase64Encoded: false
}
```

Why does this happen? It's causing me some issues in my endpoints.

Note: I can give more info if requested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because AWS Lambda events change depending on who sent it, for example:

- Database events ([AWS DynamoDB Event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb.html))
- Queue Events ([AWS SQS Event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html))
- API Events ([AWS API Gateway Event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html))
- [Events sent form other Lambda functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property)
- [Many more...](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-services.html)

You can simulate any of those events locally using `serverless invoke local` or `aws lambda invoke` and pass a local *json* payload to the function as you are currently doing, but if you send that same data through an [AWS API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) endpoint, your function will receive it as a [API Gateway Event](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/blob/main/sample-apps/nodejs-apig/event.json).

The easiest way to know all the event types and prevent errors is to use the [@types/aws-lambda](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/aws-lambda) module.